# How to add massaction in product grid in magento2?

Tags: magento2

I need to add mass action based on Settings.

If in Configuration settings, it is set to "Yes/Enable" than only that particular mass-action should be added to product grid.

I know I can directly add mass-action using ui_component product_listing.xml.
?
But case is how to check Configuration settings and add or remove based on that?

Comment: Also if not possible with ui_component - product_listing.xml, than the other way I think is to do it with event observer.

but again I am not able to do it with either way with event observer also.

Comment: I tried to do it using a plugin, but unsuccessfully. I don't know how to disable the `action` element inside the child components of the mass-action. If my research is interesting for you I can post it as an answer later.

Comment: For event observer, please check this question

http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148638/magento2-adminhtml-catalog-product-grid-prepare-massaction-event-is-not-observed

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau Means you want to remove an item from mass-action drop-down.?

Comment: Yes, I tried to make it, but without success :(

Answer (score 2):

To add a custom mass action to ui grid based on some condition you can use custom class for massaction ui component:

```
<!--/app/code/YourNamespace/YourModule/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <massaction name="listing_massaction" class="YourNamespace\YourModule\Ui\CustomMassAction"/>
    </listingToolbar>
</listing>
```

And implement this class extending the core component from Magento_Ui module.

```
namespace YourNamespace\YourModule\Ui;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction;
class CustomMassAction extends MassAction
{
    public function prepare()
    {
        parent::prepare();

        if ($this->isEnabled()) {
            $config = $this->getConfiguration();
            $config['actions'][] = [
                'component' => 'uiComponent',
                'type' => 'custom',
                'label' => 'Custom',
                'url' => '//google.com'
            ];
            $this->setData('config', $config);
        }
    }

    public function isEnabled()
    {
        return true; // access your configuration here
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can apply vice-versa approach :) . Specify configuration for your massaction in `product_listing.xml` and remove your action from configuration in custom massaction class if it is disabled in your configuration.

Another way to customize mass actions is adding a plugin for `Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction::prepare`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add mass actions to Magento 2 admin grid using the following XML in the grid XML file:

```xml
<listingToolbar name="listing_top">
    <settings>
        <sticky>true</sticky>
    </settings>
    <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
    <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
    <filters name="listing_filters"/>
    <paging name="listing_paging"/>
    <massaction name="listing_massaction">
        <action name="update_status">
            <settings>
                <type>update_status</type>
                <label translate="true">Update status</label>
                <actions class="{Namespace}\{Module}\Ui\Component\MassAction\Status\Options"/>
            </settings>
        </action>
        <action name="delete">
            <settings>
                <confirm>
                    <message translate="true">Are you sure to delete selected items?</message>
                    <title translate="true">Delete items</title>
                </confirm>
                <url path="{frontname}/{controller}/{action}"/>
                <type>delete</type>
                <label translate="true">Delete</label>
            </settings>
        </action>
        ...
    </massaction>
    ...
</listingToolbar>
```

You then need to create your own controller and actions class if necessary. [How to add mass action to Magento 2 admin grid?](https://www.hungersoft.com/info/add-mass-actions-to-admin-grid-magento2) explains in detail how to add mass actions to your Magento 2 admin grid.