# Magento2 adminhtml_catalog_product_grid_prepare_massaction event is not observed

Tags: magento2, event-observer, magento-2.1

I am trying to observe this event:

**Event Name** : adminhtml_catalog_product_grid_prepare_massaction

**Defined in** : \vendor\magento\module-catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Grid.php

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch('adminhtml_catalog_product_grid_prepare_massaction', ['block' => $this]);
```

Here is my events.xml

app\code\Mypackage\Massproductaction\etc\adminhtml\events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="adminhtml_catalog_product_grid_prepare_massaction">
        <observer instance="Mypackage\Massproductaction\Observer\Addmassactions" name="custom_add_massaction"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

Here is my observer

app\code\Mypackage\Massproductaction\Observer\Addmassactions.php

```
<?php
namespace Mypackage\Massproductaction\Observer;

class Addmassactions implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

    protected $scopeConfig;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    /**
     * Execute observer
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {
        exit("Should come here.");
    }
}
```

Few of other events are working fine.

As it is defined, why it is not working?
I want to add some dynamic mass-actions based on Settings (Configurations), so in this observer I will check the settings and will add to mass action to admin product grid.

I know it can be done with ui_component >> product_listing.xml

But as I told, I need it condition based.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this is **because the catalog product grid is using UI Components and not using the old Grid block anymore.**

This event is only triggered for grid blocks such as the newsletter subscriber grid (in 2.1.2).

**The plan is, in the future, to have all admin grids and forms (as well as frontend ones) using UI Components** so this event will pretty much be useless/deprecated AFAIK.

Comment: Any other way to have condition based ui component?